# Array of hashes, finding key value pairs

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

```
    twitter_data
  [{"LaunchAcademy"=>
   {"description"=>
     "A 10 week, intensive bootcamp teaching you how to code with a focus on Ruby on Rails",
    "last twenty tweets"=>
     ["RT @chrisccerami: While learning web development I created a map of all of the shows @Screamales have played and damn @DonGiovanniRecs http…",
      "6 ways to quantify your code and why you need to do it:  by @kevinrcasey ,
      "Do more of what you want at work. How to create productive partnerships:  by @benvoss",
      "RT @Pistachio: SO rad. bunch of local women learning to code with @gdiBoston at @HubSpot right now: ,
      "RT @STWatkins78: Huge breakthrough on my breakable toy today...can upload local file to soundcloud from my app...time for a beer! #LaunchAc…",
      "Just say yes to opportunities, especially if they scare you. great advice by @kerry_benjamin1",
      "How the internet is changing software and business, using Ruby as an example:  by  @ukitazume ,
      "RT @chrisccerami: @JustusEapen @LaunchAcademy @MarsCuriosity ,
      "Come build some interesting projects! @womenwhocode Hack Night tomorrow. RSVP:,
      "RT @SpencerCDixon: One of the greatest parts of being a developer is the massive amount of control you have over a computer. Feels very emp…",
      "7 reasons to love Minitest for testing Ruby code:  by @FluxusFrequency, a graduate from our friends @gschool",
      "Interested in becoming a game developer? Here's how:  via @skilledup ,
      "Web developer hiring trends, and what they mean for you: by @walesmd ,
      "RT @chrisccerami: I recently built my first API in Rails which I hope makes photos from Mars courtesy of @MarsCuriosity more accessible to …",
      "Build things that last. Make sure your work lives beyond you. by @acolangelo",
      "Thanks to everyone who came to Ship It! Saturday! Check out the latest blog post for a recap:,
      "Write your code as if your best friend's inheriting it  by @MGraybosch,
      "Coding can improve the way we run the world. Old, but inspiring TED talk by @pahlkadot: ,
      "Practicing pitches and getting ready for Career Day, coming up on January 27th and 28th! ,
      "RT @lizvdk: The cool kids use GEOjson so I did too. Here's how I build it with Ruby: ],
    "number of followers"=>3590,
    "number of friends"=>699,
    "latest tweet"=>
     "RT @chrisccerami: While learning web development I created a map of all of the shows @Screamales have played and damn @DonGiovanniRecs http…",
    "number of tweets"=>1433,
    "location"=>"Boston, MA"}},
 {"dpickett"=>
   {"description"=>"Co-Founder at @LaunchAcademy, Co-Organizer of @bostonrb",
    "last twenty tweets"=>
     ["RT @MeetingBoy: If your employees worked until 3AM, you have failed as a manager.",
      "Glad to see two organizations that are near and dear to me (@EntrepreneurOrg and @YEC) at the top of this list: ,
      "@lizvdk I had the same reaction - it was like they spent the last 45 minutes  trolling the movie industry.",
      "RIP @jamesgolick - I learned so much from you, and always thought you were one of the most professional and skilled devs I've ever met :-(",
      "Aspiring devs, if you need an example of a professional that embodies all we try to teach and more, look to @hchood Thank you! I'll miss you",
      "Some notes for my facilitation tomorrow on debugging JavaScript: ,
      "@marcomorawec and @kenmazaika great having you guys at Mission Control! Love meeting folks with their hearts in technical education :-)",
      "RT @graysky: \"Resumes suck. Here’s the data.\" by @alinelernerLLC Most create similar, unhelpful resume",
      "@paulanthonywils @searls @markbates I reported the @bostonrb imitator as spam. Seems like the right thing to do",
      "@divineanimal @LaunchAcademy we're delighted to have you! :-) See you soon and keep us posted on how prelearning is going.",
      "sad to hear about @ezmobius passing. His work at @engineyard and some of his conference talks blew my mind. A source of wisdom for many. RIP",
      "Thank you! ,
      "@jboursiquot happy birthday man!",
      "lol! the irony of this error message!,
      "such refreshing honesty \"If you really believe that you and your business are one, business failure destroys you\,
      "RT @bostonrb: Instead of our monthly meeting, we're going to party in December! Join us at the Black Rose on 12/9 @ 7PM. RSVP @ https://t.c…",
      "@dan_kleiman @LaunchAcademy @heroiceric Mr. G is shedding a tear right now.",
      "@kdaigle I always consider there to be a 2 or 3 year lag in enterprise adoption of ideas like that.",
      "Change is good. \"Why Google doesn’t care about hiring top college graduates\" by @MaxNisen",
      "This is why I can't read TechCrunch. What an uninformed piece, and a total misunderstanding of the term \"full stack\],
    "number of followers"=>1604,
    "number of friends"=>874,
    "latest tweet"=>
     "RT @MeetingBoy: If your employees worked until 3AM, you have failed as a manager.",
    "number of tweets"=>3451,
    "location"=>"ÜT: 42.132759,-71.132183"}},
```

Im a little stuck on printing out select keys and their values.

example: I know to print each of the users and their number of followers

```
puts "Each username followed by total number of followers."
twitter_data.each do |data|
  puts "#{data.keys[0]}: #{data[data.keys[0]]["number of followers"]}"
end
```

How do I find the user with the most number of followers?

is there a way to compare the key value pair of "number of followers" => # of followers between each of the hashes in the array.

Comment: It'd be ideal if you had a more *minimal* example here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is this:

```
twitter_data.max_by { |data| data.values.first['number of followers'] }
```